# ArrayList Exception

Tags: java, arraylist

So im currently testing ArrayList and with the code below, im always getting a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` at line 23. I read the documentation and it states

> it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection
>   while another thread is iterating over it

but im not modifying the collection while iterating over it, im doing it beforehand, so im not sure what im doing wrong here.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListIterator<String> lt = a.listIterator();
        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        String s = scanner.nextLine();

        while (!s.equals("")) {
            a.add(s);
            System.out.print("Enter another word: ");
            s = scanner.nextLine();
        }

        while (lt.hasNext()) {
            String z = lt.next(); // line 23
            System.out.println(z);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please search before asking as this sort of question has been asked many times previously. You need to modify the list *with the iterator*

Answer (score 2):

But you are, you have created the iterator before a loop that adds to the ArrayList. Move the creation of the iterator to after the first loop.

Comment: Ok thanks, that works. I thought i might create the iterator whenever i want, as long as im not actively using or iterating with it. But i was wrong with that.